# Is there a way to get the average price of products from an html table through php and add the result as a last row to that table?

Tags: php, html, arrays, average

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta sharset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Project 1</title>
<style>
table
{
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        $smartphones = array ( 'Huawei Y7 2019' => 149,
                                'Samsung Galaxy A10' => 169,
                                'Xiaomi Redmi Note 8T' => 199,
                                 'Apple iPhone 7' => 398,
                                 'Samsung Galaxy Note9' => 550);
        printsmartphones($smartphones);
        function printSmartphones ($table)
        {
            echo "<table border='2'>
            <tr>
            <th>Smartphones</th>
            <th>Price(€)</th>";
            foreach($table as $key => $value)
            {
                echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td style=\"text-align:right; color:black\">$value</td></tr>\n";
            }

            echo "</table>";
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

In this project i have to print a table in a certain way. The table will show the smartphones names on the left column and their price on the right column. At the last row it will calculate and print the average price of all the smartphones. That's where i am stack with my code, any idea how it's been done?
I am learning php by myself and i couldn't find anything anywhere.I thought of using the array_push() but i have no idea where or how.

Comment: Where is your attempt at resolving this yourself?  Please update your question with that portion of your code and explain what trouble you're encountering with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Average is the sum of all values divided by it's count. So with this you can add just another row after the foreach loop.

```
$average = array_sum($smartphones) / count($smartphones);
echo "<tr><td>Average</td><td>{$average}</td></tr>", PHP_EOL;
```